# Display a javascript function as plaintext

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object with a defined function

```
var obj = {
    addOne : function( arg1 ) { return arg1++; }
};
```

At an onclick event, I want to display the function as plaintext.  That is to say I want to somehow get the plaintext string 'function( arg1 ) { return arg1++; }' from obj so that I can display this string in a div block.

How do?

(To be clear, I am fine with printing out the string in an html element, but unclear on how to get the desired string in the first place)

Comment: See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var str = obj.addOne.toString();
```

it's that easy

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5qZse/)

Comment: In fact, that may not even be necessary because toString() is automatically called when you set a HTMLElement's textContent.

Comment: I very much enjoy when a solution turns out this simple.

Comment: @Bart - Yup, `toString()` is called when you try to reference a function in some place where a string is expected, but there's no harm in explicitly calling it here.